# hiding part of table using javascript without changing the table layout

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, show-hide

EDIT: okay I put everything in the script tag in a

```
$(document).ready(function) {
```

So now the evenTd's do hide.

I have a table and the code is below

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>itemOne</td>
        <td class="evenTd">itemTwo</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Now, I want it so that at the beggining, the first td is the only td which is visible (anything in evenTd should not be visible). After that, I want it so that when you click the first td (itemOne) then itemTwo slides and appears. So far I have

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.evenTd').hide();
});
```

and it is hiding the evenTd's, however, now the td's which don't have the evenTd class are taking up the entire screen. How do I make it so that the layout doesn't change?

Comment: Works fine here http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/4GW38/. You're either not including jQuery, or running the code before the table exists.

Comment: Just in case, are you aware about http://api.jquery.com/even-selector/ ?

Comment: okay turns out I needed the document.ready function. And ues I am aware of that selector, just didn't want to use it at the momement but thanks.

Comment: _"the other td which is inside the non hidden td's class"_. The code you posted doesn't match this. One TD is not inside another there.

Comment: @j08691 sorry, I rephrased the question

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If this is the entirety of your code, and this appears *before* the relevant elements (whether in the `head` or `body` elements, the problem is that the script is run before the DOM nodes exist.

Therefore, you can *either* place this in `$(document).ready()`:

```
<script> 
    $(document).ready(function(){   
        $('.evenTd').hide();
    });
</script>
```

Or place the script *after* the elements, in the HTML, upon which you want to act.

```
<body>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>itemOne</td>
            <td class="evenTd">itemTwo</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <script>    
        $('.evenTd').hide();
    </script>
</body>
```

Do bear in mind, though, that adding and removing individual table cells is likely to cause layout problems, it's probably better to hide the descendant elements of the relevant `td`, rather than the `td` itself.

For example, given the current HTML:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>itemOne</td>
        <td class="evenTd"><div>itemTwo</div></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

And:

```
$(document).ready(function(){   
    $('.evenTd').hide();
});
```

This gives: [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/XDQSM/), causing the single visible `td` to take up the whole row-space.

Using the above HTML with the following jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){   
    $('.evenTd div').hide();
});
```

This gives: [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/XDQSM/1/), which still demonstrates layout-changes (because there's no visual content to show inside of the `td`), but the `td` remains visible (so it's a marginally-smaller change).

The following jQuery simply makes the content of the `td` 'hidden' (so it's not visible on the page, but is still 'there' taking up space in the document's flow):

```
$(document).ready(function(){   
    $('.evenTd div').css('visibility','hidden');
});
```

This gives: [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/XDQSM/2/).

I would, however, prefer, certainly if this visibility is to be restored at some point, to add, or remove, a class on the `td` itself, and use CSS to address the specifics of each state:

```
$(document).ready(function(){   
    $('.evenTd').addClass('hidden');
    $('tr').on('click', 'td.evenTd', function(){
        $(this).toggleClass('hidden');
    });
});
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/XDQSM/3/).

Comment: Right, it did cause layout changes when I hid the evenTd's.. what do you mean by 'hiding the descendant elements'.. how would I go about doing so?

Answer (score 1):

You need to wait for DOM, before doing any Action:

```
<script type="JavaScript">
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
     jQuery('td').hide().click(function(){
          jQuery('td.visible').toggle().removeClass('visible');
          jQuery(this).toggle().addClass('visible');
     });
     jQuery('td')[1].show().addClass('visible');
 </script>
```

To show and hide elements you can use **toggle()** method.

Comment: `jQuery('td')[1].show().addClass('visible');` shouldn't work, since an `HTMLTDElement has no method 'show'`, perhaps you meant `eq()`?

Answer (score -1):

```
<td id="cell32">cell data</td>

cell32 = document.getElementById("cell32");
cell32.style.display = "none";
```